# Saving changes in TiddlyWiki

Tags: tiddlywiki

I've been using Tiddlyspace for my personal notes for a while, but I've decided I would like a locally stored solution.
I thought the obvious choice would be keeping a TiddlyWiki stored on my computer. However, the default method for saving (click the save icon, browser saves a new copy of the Wiki) seems incredibly clunky. Is there really no way to get around this while still using a browser?
I don't want to use TiddlyDesktop because I plan to use links to open other browser tabs.

Comment: also, TiddlyDesktop v.13 disk size usage looks awful to me. 200 MB in the zip file and 600 MB once you've taken it out. i viewed this tool as a rather lightweight single file and a desktop app seemed to just want to destroy that.

Answer (score 1):

I've just used this solution, which is based on Node.js, but uses TiddlyWiki in your browser: https://github.com/frankrousseau/TiddlyWiki
So far, looks really good. It even autosaves when you create a Tiddler, or stop editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of NoteSelf, which may suit your needs:

https://noteself.github.io

NoteSelf is a tiddlywiki edition that uses Pouchdb behind the scenes. This allows you to configure a remote couchdb-like database where you can synchronize to. Then you can configure several users for that database and allow different access levels. It's not tested on environments with lots of users, but it works for me with a couple of them.

My recommendation is to use the online version of it, which is available at

https://noteself.github.io/online